# Bootstrap 4 cards column into 2 rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to arrange 2 columns instead of 3 columns. I understand I can use CSS to overwrite and get 2 columns like shown below but I'm wondering if there's a bootstrap method out of the box:

```
.card-columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

This is HTML:

```
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card This is a longer card This is a longer card This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

**DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/no8z36sc/**

Answer (score 1):

1) Rename your 'card-columns' class with 'row' class.

2) Add 'col-3' class for all card div.

Your code should look like this,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card col-3">
    <p>This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-3">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-3">
    <p>This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-3">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-3">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-3">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-3">
    <p>This is a longer card This is a longer card This is a longer card This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card col-3">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from your question you are trying to show 2 cards in a single row,
try this

```
 <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="card">
           <p>This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to 
              additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
           </p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="card">
           <p>This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to 
              additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
           </p>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: there's no point in repeating all the variations -- if they will be the same at all viewports just use `col-6`

Comment: No. This would create a gap if one of the card content is not the same length.

Comment: Above code will give 2 columns of same width in a single row, but if you are trying to make card vertically equal if content length varies, you can use class="card h-100". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Uptil now there does not exist any Bootstrap `class` which are used for `column-count` css property

This issue was raised back in `2017` on `Github` but still bootstrap has no such feature of arranging `columns` with the help of the classes

---

Yet there is a solution of this without using `CSS`. Since developers building features that are required in `bootstrap`

For example you cannot set width for small devices like this: `w-sm-75` or on medium devices like this `w-md-50`

Bootstrap `width` property can only be used like `w-75` or `w-100` and so on.

---

There exist an external `stylesheet CDN` link that works with `bootstrap`, which is currently in development mode and constantly including features based on developers need's

With the help of this sheet you can set `width` for different devices

`w-sm-50 w-md-100 w-50`

It also contain `column-count` property in it using class like `car-col-2`

`car` is defining card

`col` is defining the number of columns

`2` is defining how many number of columns you want, right now it has range from `1` to `6`

So this is how your work will look like if you use `car-col-2` css class

**One important thing:** This feature haven't been introduced with different devices yet.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Stylesheet for card-columns-count and for some other features currently in development mode -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1jLrfISsLUcRiwgNl0koSfsS6lylj0E7h">




<div class="card-columns car-col-2">
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card This is a longer card This is a longer card This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <p>This is a longer card</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/urqf0e61/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using CSS grid layout easily. To adjust the number of columns set NO_OF_COLUMNS as per your requirement in CSS property grid-template-columns: repeat(NO_OF_COLUMNS, 1fr);

```
.card {
      padding: 15px;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
 }

.card-columns{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
      grid-column-gap: 20px;
      grid-row-gap: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

For more information, you can refer to https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-layout-fr-unit/

JS-Fiddle Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xskrtfgq/